# Can I safely move an App Service Plan to new different Resource Group without affecting the Apps in the plan?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, move, azure-service-plan

I've seen several similar questions like this one on SO, but none asking quite the same thing as I'm asking. Ultimately, I'm trying to move some App Services from one Service Plan in a diff resource group to a new Service Plan in the same resource group, but azure won't let me directly move the App Services across Service plans that are in different resource groups. So, my thought is to move the Service Plan into the right resource group first (which Azure seems to be willing to let me do), then move the services out of that Service Plan and into the right one..

So, in short, my question is: can I safely move a Service Plan to another resource group without affecting the App Services in the plan?

My specific scenario:

Resource Group 1

- App Service 1, Service Plan 2A
- App Service 2, Service Plan 2A
- Service Plan 1A (new)

Resource Group 2

- App Service 3, Service Plan 2A
- Service Plan 2A

All resources and groups are in under the same subscription and same geo region.

Can I safely move Service Plan 2A to RG1, without really affecting the app services in the plan (e.g. IP addresses, SSL certs, etc.)? Once that's done, can I believe I can move App Service 1 & 2 to the new Service Plan 1A, then move Service Plan 2A back to RG2.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

From [Move an app to another App Service plan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-plan-manage#move-an-app-to-another-app-service-plan)

> You can move an app to another App Service plan, as long as the source plan and the target plan are in the same resource group and geographical region.

Comment: ...not sure if my question was unclear. I am asking can I move the service PLAN to a new resource group. The service plan is currently in a diff resource group than the app's in the service plan.  I need to move the service plan into the same group as the apps.